# Short circuiting window.location without triggering refresh when value undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm adding a click handler to a table row, but as my script might run also for tables without an href attribute present, I want to make sure it doesn't break. I wanted to use short circuit to catch both cases:

```
// clicking on an entire row changes the current url
$("tbody tr").click(function() {
  debugger;
  window.location = $(this).attr("href") || void(0);
});
```

The problem is that in case the `href` attribute is undefined (hence: `false`), setting `window.location` to `void(0)` causes the page to refresh.

Is there a way to do this without using a ternary operator or an if/then/else statement?

Comment: Why set the value if there is no href?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So do not select it if i does not have the attribute.

```
$("tbody tr[href]").click(function() {
  //if ($(this).attr("href").length)
  window.location = $(this).attr("href");
});
```

or do not call it

```
$("tbody tr").click(function() {
  var href = $(this).attr("href");
  if (href) {
    window.location = href;
  }
});
```

Personally I would use data attributes and not an href.

```
<tr data-href="//example.com">
```

and than use data() to reference it

```
var href = $(this).data("href")
```

Comment: what if href is present but empty :)

Comment: Than add a simple length check, its not rocket science. ;)

Comment: hehe I know I know, was just trying to write the shortest most elegant solution possible (thought short circuiting would be an option) but yeah the attribute selector is a life saver (and saves you from trigger an event for nothing)

Answer (score 0):

```
    $("tbody tr").click(function() {
        var link = $(this).attr("href");

        if (link && link.length) {
            window.location = link;
        }

    });
```